# Pandas countif based on multiple conditions, result in new column

Tags: python, pandas, count

How can I add a field that returns 1/0 if the value in any specified column in not NaN?

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                   'val1': [2,2,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2],
                   'val2': [7,0.2,5,8,np.nan,1,0,np.nan,1,1],
                  })
display(df)
mycols = ['val1', 'val2']
# if entry in mycols != np.nan, then df[row, 'countif'] =1; else 0
```

Desired output dataframe:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not need countif logic in `pandas` , try `notna` + `any`

```
df['out'] = df[['val1','val2']].notna().any(1).astype(int)
df
Out[381]: 
   id  val1  val2  out
0   1   2.0   7.0    1
1   2   2.0   0.2    1
2   3   NaN   5.0    1
3   4   NaN   8.0    1
4   5   NaN   NaN    0
5   6   1.0   1.0    1
6   7   NaN   0.0    1
7   8   NaN   NaN    0
8   9   NaN   1.0    1
9  10   2.0   1.0    1
```

Comment: I also just realized this will work, in case someone else has this question and wants multiple options: `df['countif'] = df[df[mycols] != np.nan].count(axis=1).apply(lambda x: 1 if x > 0 else 0)`

Comment: @a11 we should try to avoid apply , more detail see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-not-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code

Answer (score 0):

Using iloc accessor filtre last two columns. Check if the sum of not NaNs in each row is more than zero. Convert resulting Boolean to integers.

```
 df['countif']=df.iloc[:,1:].notna().sum(1).gt(0).astype(int)



id  val1  val2  countif
0   1   2.0   7.0        1
1   2   2.0   0.2        1
2   3   NaN   5.0        1
3   4   NaN   8.0        1
4   5   NaN   NaN        0
5   6   1.0   1.0        1
6   7   NaN   0.0        1
7   8   NaN   NaN        0
8   9   NaN   1.0        1
9  10   2.0   1.0        1
```